# Como retornar uma consulta mysql como link?

Tags: php, mysql

Pessoal eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação, e eu gostaria de quando fosse realizado uma busca pelo formulário de pesquisa retornasse um valor como link de uma determinada página associada ao nome pesquisado, alguém sabe me dizer como fazer isso?

Aqui a parte do código que traz os resultados:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' AND cidade = '$cidade'";
$resultados = $conexao->query($sql);


if ($resultados->num_rows > 0) {
    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
        echo utf8_encode("<strong>Nome: </strong>" . $linha['nome'] . "</br>");
        print ("<strong>Endereço: </strong>" . $linha['endereco']."</br>");
        if( isset($_POST['cidade']) && $_POST['cidade'] === 'sao-gabriel-da-palha' ) {
            $fromPerson = 'São Gabriel da Palha';
            echo "<strong>Cidade: </strong>".$fromPerson."</br>";
        }
        print ("<strong>Telefone: </strong>" . $linha['telefone']."</br>");
        echo "<strong>email: </strong>". $linha['email']."</br>";
        echo "<hr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Nenhum resultado para a sua busca.";
}
```

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque a parte do código que está retornando o resultado.

Comment: na tabela empresa você tem uma coluna com o endereço do site ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para resolver eu usei uma condição, dai deu tudo certo!
Para cada nome cadastrado to usando essa condição:

```
 if (isset($_POST['nome']) === 'Empresa Cadastrada' || 'Empresa' || 'Cadastrada'){
            echo '<strong>Entre em contato por aqui: </strong><a href="empresa.php"'.$linha['link'].'>'.$linha['link'].'</a></br>';
        } else{
            echo "Empresa não associada";
        }
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor? Assim acho que a sua resposta não vai ajudar muito se alguém tiver o mesmo problema.

Comment: editei, veja ai !

Comment: Obrigado, melhorou

Answer (score 4):

> verifique se na sua tabela **empresa** tem a coluna **site** / **url**, caso não tenha, crie e coloque essa linha dentro do **while**:

```
echo "<strong>site: </strong>". $linha['site']."</br>";
```

Ficando assim o código:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' AND cidade = '$cidade'";
$resultados = $conexao->query($sql);


if ($resultados->num_rows > 0) {
    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
        echo utf8_encode("<strong>Nome: </strong>" . $linha['nome'] . "</br>");
        print ("<strong>Endereço: </strong>" . $linha['endereco']."</br>");
        if( isset($_POST['cidade']) && $_POST['cidade'] === 'sao-gabriel-da-palha' ) {
            $fromPerson = 'São Gabriel da Palha';
            echo "<strong>Cidade: </strong>".$fromPerson."</br>";
        }
        print ("<strong>Telefone: </strong>" . $linha['telefone']."</br>");
        echo "<strong>email: </strong>". $linha['email']."</br>";
        // Mostra o link para site
        echo '<strong>site: </strong><a href="'.$linha['site'].'">'.$linha['site'].'</a></br>';
        echo "<hr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Nenhum resultado para a sua busca.";
}
```

Comment: beleza na tabela vou adicionar o campo para inserir o link, eu não tinha pensado dessa forma, muito obrigado!

Comment: ai tem um problema, desse jeito ai todos os os links serão setados com o mesmo valor

Comment: Não tem como retornar com o mesmo valor.